# How to position folder in Openide Layer

Tags: java, xml, openide

I want to put a sub-menu in my file menu.  Writing the class doesn't work, so I put a folder in my module's layer.xml.  Now I can't specify where to put it.  How do specify the location of a sub-menu folder in layer.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me forever to figure out.  It is as simple as adding `<attr name=position intvalue="pos"/>` after the folder declaration  where `pos` is where you want your folder placed.  The result looks like this:

```
<folder name="myFolder">
    <attr name="position" intvalue="0"/>
</folder>
```